# Can a rotation always be distance increasing?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

#### Objects

1. The circle $S^1$
2. A non-trivial rotation $f: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ given by $f(z) = e^{i\theta}z$ for $\theta \ne 0$
3. A non-standard metric $d: S^1 \times S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ which induces the standard topology on $S^1$

#### Question

Given $(S^1,d)$ with a non-standard metric $d$ and a rotation $f$ as above, can we always find close by points $x,y$ such that $d(f(x),f(y)) \leq d(x,y)$?

Alternatively, is there a non-standard metric $d$ on $S^1$ where a rotation is locally distance-increasing?

#### Thoughts

Proof by contradiction.

Assume there is a $d$ where a rotation $f$ is locally distance-increasing. Then $f^{-1}$ is locally distance-decreasing in the metric $d$. Can we using the distance-decreasing property to obtain a fixed point for $f^{-1}$ and contradict the fact that $f^{-1}$ has no fixed point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rational rotation - where the angle is a rational multiple of $\pi$ - has the property that for some integer $n > 0, f^n(x) = x$ for all $x \in S^1$. For such a rotation, if there exist $x_0, y_0$ such that $d(f(x_0), f(y_0)) < d(x_0, y_0)$, then for all $i > 0$, define $x_i = f(x_{i-1})$ and similarly for $y_i$. Because $x_n = x_0, y_n = y_0$, there has to be some $i \le n$ such that $d(x_i, y_i) > d(x_{i-1}, y_{i-1})$. Otherwise we would have $d(x_n, y_n) = d(x_0, y_0) < d(x_0, y_0)$. So a rational rotation cannot be locally decreasing everywhere without being an isometry with respect to $d$. Similarly, a rational rotation cannot be locally increasing everywhere without being an isometry.

For irrational rotations, it is going to depend on what you mean by "locally". If locally is defined with respect to the standard metric, then no, the only metrics with a locally monotonic rotation are those where the rotation is an isometry. Even though for irrational rotations, $f^n(x) \ne x$ for any $x$ or $n$, it is still the case that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $n > 0$ such that for all $x, |f^n(x) - x| < \epsilon$, where $|\cdot |$ is the standard norm. This allows an approximate version of the argument above for rational rotations to be applied. By refining the approximation, the same result follows.

But if you define "locally" by $d$ instead of the standard metric, then you are no longer talking about $S^1$. It is just an uncountable set of points that you can do whatever you like with. And an irrational rotation is just a bijection without cycles on that set (i.e., $f^n(x) \ne x$ for all $n,x$). You can define equivalence classes by $x \sim y \iff \exists n\in \Bbb Z, f^n(x) = y$. Then you can define $d$ by making the distance between elements of distinct equivalence classes to be $1$, while within the same equivalence class $d(x, f^n(x)) = r^n$ for some $r > 0, r\ne 1$. Under this metric, $f$ will be increasing or decreasing depending on whether $r > 1$ or $r < 1$.

Comment: There is an asymmetry problem in my definition of $d$ at the end that is deeper than I thought yesterday. I do not have the time to figure out how to fix it now, but I believe a variant of the idea should work.